# If A is a σ-algebra, then A = σ(A).

Tags: measure-theory

Show that if $A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra then $\sigma(A)=A$.

My proof:
$\sigma(A)=A\iff\text{$\sigma(A)\subset A$ and $A\subset\sigma(A)$}$.

We have always $A\subset\sigma(A)$ but i don't know how to show the other way around.
I got some hint from the book such as:
Since $A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, $A$ ‘competes’ in the intersection of all $\sigma$-algebras $M \supset A$ appearing in the def: $\sigma(A)\mathrel{:=}\bigcap M$ where $M$ is $\sigma$−Algebra and $M\supseteq A$.

Is a good explanation to say that since the $\sigma(A)$ is an intersection it will be always "smaller" than every sigma algebra generating the intersection, so $\sigma(A)$ is contained in $A$ and I finished.

Comment: $\sigma (\mathcal G)$ is the smallest $\sigma -$algebra which contains $\mathcal G$. Since $\mathcal G$ is a $\sigma -$algebra that contains $\mathcal G$, then $\sigma (\mathcal G)\subset \mathcal G$.

Comment: I think @Surb is [saying](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4538630/if-a-is-a-σ-algebra-then-a-σa#comment9541709_4538630), and I agree, that, yes, your proposed explanation is fine, except that for "smaller" I would say "contained in" (keeping in mind that an intersection can equal, rather than being *strictly* smaller than, one of its ‘intersectands’).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: For future reference, @JoséCarlosSantos's [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4538630/if-a-is-a-σ-algebra-then-a-σa#comment9541713_4538630) (presumably) applied to the non-TeX'd, original version of the question; I just [edited](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/4538630/4) to TeX.  I also fixed a typo along the way, where you referred to the intersection of all $\sigma$-algebras $A \supset A$; almost certainly you meant all $\sigma$-algebras $M \supset A$, so I edited accordingly.  I did not edit to change $\subset$ vs. $\subseteq$, which you seem to use interchangeably.

Comment: Ok thank you! Nice to hear that my explanation was almost fine and certainly it's better to say "contained in".

Answer (score 1):

$\sigma(A)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the sets in $A$, where smallest means that if $\mathscr{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra with $A\subseteq\mathscr{A}$, then $\sigma(A)\subseteq\mathscr{A}$. Then in your case, we assume that $A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, and clearly $A\subseteq A$, so by the above we have that

$$\sigma(A)\subseteq A.$$

But by definition,

$$A\subseteq\sigma(A).$$

It follows by the two inclusions that $A=\sigma(A)$.

Comment: Thank you! Was my explanation correct ?

Comment: @GabrielePillitteri if I understand you correctly, your explanation is that if $\sigma(A)=\bigcap_{M}M$, and $B\in M$, then $B\in\sigma(A)$, effectively saying that $M\subseteq\sigma(A)$? If that is what you're saying then yeah that is correct, and is essentially what I'm saying at the start of my answer as well

Comment: What I'm saying is that σ(A)=⋂M, and B∈M, but we know that B is for sure greater than the intersection of sigma algebras, hence B ⊇ ⋂M, so σ(A)⊆ B.

Comment: @GabrielePillitteri yeah that is correct